# ¿Añadir clase con jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Tengo esta tabla:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

y le quiero añadir con jquery una clase a todos los td menos a los ulimos y los primeros:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="1">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td class="2">Maria Anders</td>
    <td class="3">Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="4">Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td class="5">Francisco Chang</td>
    <td class="6">Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="7">Ernst Handel</td>
    <td class="8">Roland Mendel</td>
    <td class="9">Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="10">Island Trading</td>
    <td class="11">Helen Bennett</td>
    <td class="12">UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: la clase no se repite ni una vez, no seria mejor un id?

Answer (score 5):

Solo basta:

```
 $('tr:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) > td').addClass('clase');
```

**Ejemplo**

```js
$('tr:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) > td').addClass('red');
```

```css
td.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Leslie</td>
      <td>29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Sarah</td>
      <td>Wolfe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Milett</td>
      <td>Stark</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Jessie</td>
      <td>Selbst</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Aunque por supuesto puedes hacer esto directamente con CSS. Lo mejor es, en todo caso, usar clases CSS para afectar solamente los elementos que la contengan.

Comment: y si quisiera que los td del penúltimo tr tampoco tengan la clase?

Comment: En ese caso ya simplemente una itera tus filas y aplica a las deseas evitando los índices de las filas que quieres evitar.

Answer (score 0):

Y si se lo pones a todos y luego se los quitas a los últimos?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cont = 1;
  $("#idTabla tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find("td").each(function()){
      $(this).addClass(""+cont++);
    }
  });

  $("#idTabla tr:last").find("td").each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr("class");
  }); 
});
```